# Calling method from member object

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem with calling member method of object which is a member of some class. What I mean? I have class `CPosition`:

**cposition.h**

```
#ifndef CPOSITION_H
#define CPOSITION_H

class CPosition
{
public:
    CPosition(QString name, QString description);
    QString toString();

private:
    QString m_name;
    QString m_description;

};

#endif // CPOSITION_H
```

**cposition.cpp**

```
#include <QString>
#include "cposition.h"

CPosition::CPosition(QString name, QString description)
    : m_name(name), m_description(description)
{

}

QString toString()
{
    QString test("Test - method called!");
    return test;
}
```

And then I have a class `CPerson` in which one of member is pointer to `CPosition` object. In method `CPerson::getPosition` I would like to call method `CPosition::getPosition` only if pointer exist:

**cperson.h**

```
#ifndef CPERSON_H
#define CPERSON_H

class CPosition;

class CPerson
{
public:
    CPerson(QString name);
    QString getPosition();

private:
    QString m_name;
    CPosition * m_position;
    CEmployer * m_employer;
};

#endif // CPERSON_H
```

**cperson.cpp**

```
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QString>
#include "cperson.h"
#include "cposition.h"

CPerson::CPerson(QString name) : m_name(name){}

QString CPerson::getPosition()
{
    QString str;
    QTextStream cout(&str);
    if(m_position) //here check if pointer exist
    {
        cout << "Position: " << m_position->toString(); //<---- here is problem
    }
    else
        cout << "Position doesn't exist!!!" << endl;
    return str;
}
```

When I build this project I get an error:

```
C:\Qt\Projects\Tutorial\qt2\cperson.cpp:28: error: undefined reference to `CPosition::toString()'
```

I'm using QtCreator IDE. Does anyone can help me with this issue or explain why this isn't working ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define your `toString()` method with

```
QString toString()
{
   //code
}
```

prototype in `cposition.cpp` file, it's not a member of the `CPosition` class. That's why when you try to call this method from `m_position` pointer which is of type `CPosition`, you get undefined reference error because you haven't implemented the `toString()` method decalred in `cposition.h` file.

Change the prototype of the `toString()` method in `cposition.cpp` file from

```
QString toString()
```

to

```
QString CPosition::toString()
{
   //write code here
}
```

so that compiler knows that `toString()` method implemented in `cposition.cpp` file is the one declared in `cposition.h` file.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are not giving an implementation to the `toString` method. The correct way should be:

```
QString CPosition::toString()
{
    QString test("Test - method called!");
    return test;
}
```